# Node.js and Heroku request timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I want to upload large file to heroku using node.js and heroku as my server. I have this code below, where i am trying to extend the request timeout but still it doesn't work.

```
app.post('/fileUpload', function(req, res) {
upload(req, res, function(err){
    req.setTimeout(100, function(){
        res.send("Timeout");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 100 is in milliseconds, which is pretty short for a file upload. Maybe try bumping that up significantly. Also, uploading files to Heroku comes with many caveats due to the "ephemeral" nature of Heroku apps. Try skimming this article and seeing if maybe you need to look at alternative options, such as direct to S3:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3